# How to use php array values in .js file?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to use input type hidden value which is array to .js file for select2 checkbox.

Php form

```
 <input type="hidden" name="post_array" id="post_array" value="<?php print_r($post_ids); ?>">
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 25171
    [1] => 25163
)
```

Value I am trying to fetch in jquery with separate .js file

```
var test = $('#post_array').val();
alert(test);
```

Output is same as php output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 25171
    [1] => 25163
)
```

I want to use array values here.

```
$("#slider_post").val(["25171"]).trigger('change.select2');
```

How can i replace `.val(["25171"])` with php array values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is to find a common format which both languages can understand, the most commonly used format used for these two languages to communicate is [JSON](https://www.json.org/), as such, you can do the following:

In your PHP file, you can define the JavaScript variable:

```
<?php

?>

<script>
let my_array = JSON.parse('<?= json_encode($my_array) ?>');
</script>

<?php
// php code...

?>
```

As per [Jon Stirling's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934966/jon-stirling) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55138742/how-to-use-php-array-values-in-js-file/55138812#comment97018130_55138812):

> The first option will only work if:
>
> a) the JS file in included afterwards,
>
> or b) the code in the js file run in a way that it runs after the document has loaded

or, using your method, you need to encode the as a JSON string via PHP then parse it as JSON in JavaScript:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="post_array" id="post_array" value="<?= json_encode($post_ids); ?>">
```

Then,

```
var test = JSON.parse($('#post_array').val());
```

**Reading Material**

[`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

[`JSON.parse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Just a note for OP, the first option will only work if a) the JS file in included afterwards, or b) the code in the js file run in a way that it runs after the document has loaded

Comment: `let my_array = <?= json_encode($my_array) ?>;` also works, eliminating the need for `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: @Script47 why? Surely an unquoted `json_encode` output is a valid JavaScript object?

Comment: @user7290573 you are quite correct, my mistake, I misunderstood what you meant.